# Custom Ribbon Button Not Appearing in Contacts List

Tags: visual-studio

Ive done some dev work with sharepoint last year but nothing like what im building today so Im not very experienced with it. I am trying to add a custom button to the ribbon in a list modeled on the contacts template. I wrote the code for the button and tested it in a custom list. For some reason it isnt showing up in the Contacts list i need it to. everything works just fine in a custom list. Heres my code;

```
<CustomAction

    Id="CsvExportButton"
    RegistrationId="100"
    RegistrationType="List"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
    Sequence="20"
    Title="Export to CSV">

    <CommandUIExtension>
        <CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.New.Controls._children">
                            <Button
                                Id="SS7.Ribbon.Customizations.Tab.Actions.Controls.ExportCSV"
                                Alt="Export selected items to CSV"
                                Sequence="20"
                                Command="CMDAlertRibbonButton"
                                LabelText="Export to CSV"
                                Image16by16="/_layouts/1033/images/formatmap16x16.png"
                                Image32by32="/_layouts/1033/images/formatmap32x32.png"
                                TemplateAlias="o1"/>
            </CommandUIDefinition>
        </CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIHandlers>
            <CommandUIHandler
            Command="CMDAlertRibbonButton"
            CommandAction="javascript:
            function resultCallback(result, value)
            {
            SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Success!');
            SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
            }

            var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
            var myItems = '';
            var i;

            for (i in items)
            {
            myItems += '|' + items[i].id;
            }

            if(myItems != '')
            {
            var options = {
            url: '{SiteUrl}/_layouts/MyPage.aspx?Items=' + myItems + '&amp;ListId={SelectedListId}&amp;Source={Source}',
            title: 'My Page',
            allowMaximize: false,
            showClose: true,
            width: 600,
            height: 600,
            dialogReturnValueCallback: resultCallback };

            SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
            }" />
        </CommandUIHandlers>


    </CommandUIExtension>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegistrationId="100" this is for generic list

you should try

RegistrationId="105" which is for Contacts

you can get the list of registration id over here:

http://sharepointwings.blogspot.in/2012/06/sharepoint-2010-list-template-type.html

Comment: Awesome list!!! I actually solved it yesterday but changing RegistrationType="ContentType" and RegistrationId="0x0106"

Comment: Your answer is more robust. Just to elaborate my solution, I changed the RegistrationType to "ContentType" to look for Content Type lists and "0x0106" is the RegistrationId for any Contacts based content type list. I found the ID by going to the site collection root>Site Settings>Site Content Types>Contacts and in the URL, the RegistrationId was in the string next to ctype=0x0106. Just another way of doing it I suppose. Im new to Sharepoint dev so I dont know which way is preferred.